# displaying custom modal on clicking a table row

Tags: html, knockout.js, jquery-click-event, durandal

I want to create custom modal. Basically, I have a table which has rows in it. When the user clicks on a row, I want a pop-up window to appear. I am following the description of how to create a custom modal in this link: http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Showing-Message-Boxes-And-Modals/

Based on the description, I figured I need two classes to create a custom modal. One is the view and another one is modal.

I actually the two classes with the exact same code in the link.

My question is, how do I display the custom modal when a row is clicked?

Let's say this is my table in my view called `index.html`

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>  
      <th></th>
      <th>Item</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>  
  <tbody>     
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And suppose I have a view called `messageBox.html`  Here's the code for it:

```
<div class="messageBox">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h3 data-bind="html: title"></h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p class="message" data-bind="html: message"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer" data-bind="foreach: options">
    <button class="btn" data-bind="click: function () { $parent.selectOption($data); }, html: $data, css: { 'btn-primary': $index() == 0, autofocus: $index() == 0 }"></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

And a modal called `messageBox.js`. Here's the code for it:

```
define(function() {
  var MessageBox = function(message, title, options) {
    this.message = message;
    this.title = title || MessageBox.defaultTitle;
    this.options = options || MessageBox.defaultOptions;
  };

  MessageBox.prototype.selectOption = function (dialogResult) {
    this.modal.close(dialogResult);
  };

  MessageBox.defaultTitle = '';
  MessageBox.defaultOptions = ['Ok'];

  return MessageBox;
});
```

How do I tie the table click event with this custom modal that I created?

Comment: I think you'll have a better chance of getting help if *you* provide the pertinent code as opposed to making other people go find it.

Comment: I got it, lemme edit my post.

Answer (score 2):

To show a modal its just like how you use the compose binding. You pass it a viewmodel you want to show and the [viewmodel locator](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/View-Locator/) will find the view based off your viewmodel.

Here is the table:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>  
      <th></th>
      <th>Item</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>  
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: items">     
    <tr data-bind="click: $parent.showMessage">
      <td data-bind="text: item"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: price"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: quantity"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is the viewmodel thats bound to the table.

```
define(['durandal/app', 'durandal/system', 'messageBox'], function(app, system, MessageBox) {
  return {
    items: ko.observableArray([
      { item: 'fruity pebbles', price: 4.5, quantity: 1 },
      { item: 'captain crunch', price: 3.5, quantity: 1 },
      { item: 'honey bunches of oats', price: 4, quantity: 1 }
    ]),
    showMessage: function(item) {
      var msg = 'your purchasing' + item.name;
      var mb = new MessageBox(msg)
      app.showModal(mb).then(function(dialogResult){
        system.log('dialogResult:', dialogResult);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

`app.showModal` takes in the viewmodel which you want to show and returns a [promise](http://api.jquery.com/promise/). That promise is passed a parameter of what you passed to the `this.modal.close(dialogResult)`.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer.Could you please provide JSFiddle for this code?

Comment: sorry, i dont know how to use jsfiddle w/ durandal

Comment: How about the view messageBox.html. How do you tie that with the viewmodel?

Comment: Download the durandal samples : http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Understanding-the-Samples/ I think this will give you a better understanding of how it works.  Also, look into composition binding to understand how durandal binds viewmodels to views and how it finds the views based off conventions. http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Composition/